# python regex find edit and replace in file

Tags: python, regex

I have text file (bio.txt) with this text :

```
Enter for a chance to {win|earn|gain|obtain|succeed|acquire|get} 
1 - Click {Link|Url|Link up|Site|Web link} Below
2 - Enter Name
3 - Do the submit(inside option {put|have|positioned|set|placed|apply|insert} address)
```

I have this python code :

```
def spyntax():
    bio_file = open('bio.txt', 'r').readlines()
    _line = ''
    for line in bio_file:
        try:
            matches = re.findall('\{([a-zA-Z| ]+)\}', line)
            for march in matches:
                tmp = random.choice(march.split('|'))
            _line += re.sub('\{([a-zA-Z| ]+)\}', tmp, line)
        except Exception as e:
            print e
    return _line
```

The code find text like this :

```
{win|earn|gain|obtain|succeed|acquire|get}
```

and replace with random choice of text group.
The problem is if in the same line exist more group text with

```
{text|text} {word1|word2}
```

then python doesn't replace correct the {}. How can I get this code to replace correctly all {} groups ?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `re.sub()` with a little helper function to pick a random string from the result and use it for the sub:

```
import re
import random

s = "Enter for a chance to {win|earn|gain|obtain|succeed|acquire|get}"

def split_rand(r):
    r = r.group(1)
    return random.choice(r.split('|'))

print re.sub('{(.*?)}', lambda r: split_rand(r), s)
```

Of if you wanted to get more minimal you could drop the function and simply:

```
re.sub('{(.*?)}', lambda r: random.choice(r.group(1).split('|')), s)
```

So you can rework the loop into your program to:

```
for line in biofile:
    _line += re.sub('{(.*?)}', lambda r: random.choice(r.group(1).split('|')), line)
```